# to_python being called every time data is loaded from DB

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have various database fields that are decrypted using the `to_python` method. The problem I'm having is that every time I access the admin section (`admin.ModelAdmin` list) for this particular model, the page takes ages to load. I don't need the `to_python` method to decrypt fields on the list page, as the fields or the columns I'm listing aren't encrypted at all. When a user clicks on an item to edit it, the `to_python` method kicks in, which is fine, exactly as intended. However, how can I stop the `to_python` method trying to decrypt the objects while listing them, bearing in mind the list view shows only fields that are not encrypted? Also, this is causing the filter to work really slowly. Again, the filtering is only done on non-encrypted fields so there shouldn't be a need for the `to_python` method to execute itself.

Comment: You might want to try overriding your ModelAdmin's Queryset method so that it delays the loading of the encrypted field. Not entirely sure about that at all though, but tell me how that goes if you feel like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the issue is that the admin will load the entire model instance for each row, even though you're only displaying a few fields. The solution should be to override the `queryset` method in your `ModelAdmin` subclass so that instead of using the standard `get_query_set` method of the default manager, it uses the `only` method to only get the fields you want:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('foo', 'bar')

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = self.model._default_manager.only('foo', 'bar')
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request)
        if ordering:
            qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
        return qs
```

(or you could use `defer('my_expensive_field')`, which amounts to the same thing).

Comment: I'm just curious, where did you come across the "self.model._default_manager.only" syntax? I've googled it and searched the Django docs and I've been unable to find any reference to ".only", is there a secret Django society I don't know about that teaches this dark art? :-)

Comment: :-) `_default_manager` is undocumented as far as I know, but `only` is a standard queryset method: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#only